# How to approach healthkit if the health app is not yet setup?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, user-permissions, healthkit

I am doing an app with healthkit integration and I am wondering what happens or what I should do if the health app is not setup or if it sets the user up when you ask for access?

I am doing this in Ionic Framework which uses Cordova if that changes anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the user to set up the Health app before you use the APIs. Just request authorization to read/write the data types you need and the system will handle showing the user the right authorization experience.